# Searching through array of objects with user input, validating input

Tags: java, arrays, validation, search, input

I'm working with validating input with these two methods in Java. The searchCandidate method searches through a sorted array to find the object whose name matches what the user input (String searchKey). The displayCandidate method calls this method, checks for validation, and returns all the values of that particular object.

In the searchCandidate (directly below) method, if it finds a match it returns a copy of the object. If it does not, it returns a new object with "null" in all fields.

```
   //Find user input candidate location in array 
     public static Candidate searchCandidate(Candidate[] candidate)
      {
        String currName;
        int first = 0,
            last = candidate.length-1,
            middle;
        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
        String searchKey = kbd.nextLine();
        searchKey = searchKey.toUpperCase();

        while(first <= last)
         {
            middle = (first + last)/2;
            currName = candidate[middle].getName();
            if(currName.equals(searchKey))
               {
                  return new Candidate(candidate[middle]);
               }
            else if(currName.compareTo(searchKey)<0)
               {
                  first=middle+1;
               }
            else
               {
                  last = middle - 1;
               }
         }

    return new Candidate("null","null","null","null");
}
```

In the displayCandidate method, it checks if the name field of the object searchCandidate creates is equal to "null", and then returns a string informing the user there is no matching candidate. If it does not equal null, it returns all the object values.

```
   //Display candidates info after search
   public static String displayCandidate(Candidate[] candidate)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of the candidate (LAST,FIRST)");                                      
        Candidate candidateChoice = searchCandidate(candidate);
        if(candidateChoice.getName().equals("null"))
          {
              return "There are no candidates with this name.";
          }
          return candidateChoice.display();
    }
```

When I run and put in the name of an object that's not in the array, nothing is returned. It simply loops back to my user menu. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: It would be a good idea to add a tag with the programming language you're using

Comment: @alfasin Slipped up, added it in. Thanks.

Comment: Try printing to your console the candidateChoice.getName() before entering the if to make sure and change "null" to something else to make sure it is refering to the string and not the state

Comment: @YassinHH I changed "null" to "empty", attempted to print out candidateChoice.getName() and the same thing happened - nothing is printed and it loops back to the menu. But when I enter a valid name, the method works as it is supposed to.

Comment: Ok. Now maybe, add to your constructor a message that says something like "Candidate created with the following values : etc.." to see if your "null" Candidate really gets created or not and to narrow the search area

Comment: @YassinHH Thank you! I found where I was going wrong, and now feel completely stupid. Where I as attempting to return a string to print, the code for the menu option was merely executing the method. So when I would return with .display() it would print fine, but the string in my if statement itself was never being printed.

Comment: LOL I get it now ! Well I'm gonna have to make a response to validate for me and the community lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we saw together in the comments, the problem was that you simply did not use the return value from the method to print it.

And the reason why it printed something while you were entering a correct Candidate name is because you used the display() method that had a print method in it.

```
if(candidateChoice.getName().equals("null"))
          {
              return "There are no candidates with this name.";
          }
return candidateChoice.display();
```

Correct solution would be to :

- Adapt the display method to display something when the `Candidate` is null

Or

- Create a new method of `Candidate` that just returns a String without displaying it containing info about the Candidate and has a special test for the null Candidates and that you would use like here

New code :

```
public static String displayCandidate(Candidate[] candidate)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the candidate (LAST,FIRST)");                                      
    Candidate candidateChoice = searchCandidate(candidate);
    return candidateChoice.getInformation();
}
```

And the getInformation() method would be something like :

```
public String getInformation(){
    if (this.getName().equals("null"){
        return "Candidate does not exist";
    }else{
        // Here belongs the information you want to display from the Candidate object
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to implement something like binary search,but that's reinventing the wheel. while you just can do this.

```
  public static Candidate searchCandidate(Candidate[] candidate)
    {
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
            String searchKey = kbd.nextLine();
            searchKey = searchKey.toUpperCase();
    int search = Arrays.binarySearch(candidate, new Candidate(searchkey,"null","null","null"), new Comparator<Candidate>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Candidate s1, Candidate s2) {
          return s1.getName().compareTo(s2.getName());
        }
     });

       if (search!=-1) 
          return candidate[search];
       else
          return Candidate(null,"null","null","null");

      }
```

Comment: I appreciate your solution, however the binary search as I have it is a requirement of the project. We also had to do a manual bubblesorting method, so there's a bit of restriction in terms of the tools we can use.

Comment: then i am sorry to tell you that you are implementing binarySearch algorithm in a totally wrong way.

Comment: It is not really helping and not bringing a solution.